# How to have MSXML 4.0 write &#xA; in XML instead of CR+LF?

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I have seen several questions about reading end-of-line or writing end-of-line for pretty formatting. It doesn't help me as I don't want to write end-of-lines but to escape them in a value.

I have the following code to write a tag value in a XML file, using MSXML 4.0:

```cpp
    a_pIXMLDOMElement->Puttext ( l_VarText );
```

`a_pIXMLDOMElement` is a `MSXML2::IXMLDOMElementPtr&`.
It doesn't escape correctly end-of-lines: when `l_VarText` contains a CR, or a CR+LF or a LF, the resulting tag's value in the XML file contains CR+LF instead of `&#xA;`.

I have tried with `preserveWhiteSpace` set to `true` on `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr` just after creating it, it changes nothing (original code was setting it to `false`).

I have tried to escape the end-of-line myself before calling `Puttext`, the result is that instead of `&#xA;` I got `&amp;#xA;` in the tag value (MSXML escapes correctly the `&`, so it mess up my escaping of end-of-lines).

How to correctly escape end-of-lines while writing XML tag values with MSXML 4.0?